# Sinatra render text file

Tags: ruby, templates, layout, sinatra, render

How do I render an html file with the layout included in Sinatra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using one of the helpers for your favourite template language. I.e., if you use `erb` something like this may work for you:

```
erb :foo
```

Noting that you'll need a `foo.erb` in your views hierarchy, and a layout named `layout` defined. If you want to use a custom layout however, this may work for your needs:

```
erb :foo, :layout => "alternate_layout"
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but isn't that slower than rendering the file as text because then `Erb` has to process it?

Comment: Sure, but most of the template engines are fast enough that it's probably not going to be an issue. If it is, post that as a question.

Comment: Oh yeah, duh. I'll just use Erb and then Varnish to cash it forever.